# ceramic caps across diode bridge?/

Tags: power-supply, error

I'm repairing a Tenma PS (straight forward 12V 4A linear) and I noticed
a couple 103Z ceramic caps on the bridge rectifier, however one cap goes
from ~AC to + and the other goes from the other ~AC post to -. What's the point on shunting those two diodes with .01s?

Comment: Picture of the board please, and model #, the best if you have reference to its schematics on the internet

Comment: The DIY amp people do this a lot for their hi-fi designs.  You say a couple.  The audio guys put one across each diode in the bridge, so four in total.

Comment: Four caps would have made sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's to reduce high frequency ringing of the circuit at the end of the capacitor charging pulses.

The charging current for the filter cap is drawn in brief high current pulses near the peak of the (roughly) sinusoidal mains-frequency input waveform. When the diode switches off you are left with leakage inductance of the transformer and stray capacitance, diode capacitance, and distributed capacitance in the coil.

The inductance and capacitance form a tank circuit that rings at relatively high frequency. Putting a capacitor in there should reduce that so the lossy terms dominate and the ringing is reduced or eliminated.

The caps are standard operating practice in audio circuits that use a linear supply.